# delete recursive directory created by robocopy when "The file name is too long"

Tags: windows-7, robocopy

After running robocopy.exe to backup a C:\Users\ folder without using the `/xj` switch, I ended up with a recursive directory which was too long. For example, if you run `dir /b /s` you will receive the following error:

The directory name C:\Users\ ... \AppData\Local\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data is too long.

I tried deleting it with `rmdir "Application Data" /s` but I received the error "The file name is too long"

I've looked at other solutions, but I thought I might be able to use the tool that *caused* the issue to *solve* it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create an empty directory with `mkdir empty`, then use `robocopy empty\ "Application Data\" /mir"` which will remove the whole directory tree. Then issue a `rmdir empty` and `rmdir "Application Data` to clean up and you're done.

Comment: +1 Unbelievable that it requires something this arcane to do something as simple as delete a folder...

Comment: This buggy infinite recursive folder was driving me crazy ! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to `cd` down deep enough into the directory to delete what's below and `cd` back up to the top again and delete what's left.

If that doesn't work and you're still stuck, download the [free demo](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Demo.htm) version of my Hamilton C shell (full disclosure:  I'm the author) and use the [`rm`](http://hamiltonlabs.com/UserGuide/Utilities/rm.htm) utility that comes with it using the `-r` (recursive) and `-x` (delete anything) options.

```
rm -rx directoryname
```

My `rm` uses the new [long Unicode filename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath) format internally, allowing it to manipulate paths up 32K characters, and that should get it.

If you discover the problem also involves permissions, you may need to use [`sudo`](http://hamiltonlabs.com/UserGuide/Utilities/su.htm) or `su` to elevate, e.g.,

```
sudo rm -rx directoryname
```

In really stubborn cases, you may be stymied by an ACL that prevents access, e.g.., `cacls` reports `Everyone:(DENY)`.  In that case you may need to remove that ACE (access control entry).

```
cacls directoryname /e /r everyone
```

Finally, I really intend for this to be helpful.  My server logs tell me people are downloading my software to try this and I want this to work.  If you encounter a case where it didn't, I hope you'll reach out to tell me so I can debug why and make it work.  Stuff you can't delete happens a lot and I'd like to have all the cases covered.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try one of the following;

**Resolution 1:** Use an auto-generated 8.3 name to access the file

**Resolution 2:** Rename or move a deep folder

**Resolution 3:** Map a drive to a folder in the structure of the path
Map a drive to a folder inside the structure of the path of the target file or folder. This method shortens the virtual path.

**Resolution 4:** Use a network share that is as deep as the folder
If Resolution 1, 2, and 3 are not convenient or do not resolve the issue, create a network share that is as deep in the folder tree as you can, and then rename the folders by accessing the share.

**Resolution 5:** Use a tool that can traverse deep paths

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320081

Comment: this solution seems to be a type of "Resolution 5: Use a tool that can traverse deep paths"